Unable to retrieve properties of joined tables with NHibernate
I have two unrelated entities in NHibernate which their ids are identical. The entities are known as Settlement and Transaction, and they are View in the DB. There are examples already with regards to how to join unrelated entities, and I used that as a guideline to try on the Views that I have. Example in the NHibernate doc.,
Cat cat = null;
Cat joinedCat = null;

var uniquelyNamedCats = sess.QueryOver<Cat>(() => cat)
    .JoinEntityAlias(
        () => joinedCat,
        () => cat.Name == joinedCat.Name && cat.Id != joinedCat.Id,
        JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .Where(() => joinedCat.Id == null)
    .List();

However, doing something similar, although I can get the result, but I could only see the Settlement records, not the Transaction, regardless if I specify the join type or not.
    Settlement settlement = null;
    Transaction Transaction = null;

    var results = GetSession().QueryOver<Settlement>(() => settlement)
        .JoinEntityAlias(() => Transaction, () => settlement.LqdTransactionId == Transaction.Lqdtransactionid)
        .Where(t => settlement.SettlementDate >= duration.StartTime &&
                                                                    settlement.SettlementDate <= duration.EndTime &&
                                                                    settlement.TransactionRegion == transactionRegion &&
                                                                    settlement.SettlementMode == AppConstantsValue.SettlementMode.Normal)
        .List();
                                  

If I try to transform the result to a non-entity POCO, I will get an exception instead.
        var results = GetSession().QueryOver<Settlement>(() => settlement)
            .Left.JoinAlias(() => Transaction, () => settlement.LqdTransactionId == Transaction.Lqdtransactionid)
            .Where(t => settlement.SettlementDate >= duration.StartTime &&
                                                                        settlement.SettlementDate <= duration.EndTime &&
                                                                        settlement.TransactionRegion == transactionRegion &&
                                                                        settlement.SettlementMode == AppConstantsValue.SettlementMode.Normal)
               .SelectList(list => list
    .Select(() => Transaction.Payeeid).WithAlias(() => settlementModel.PayeeId)
    .Select(() => Transaction.Merchantid).WithAlias(() => settlementModel.MerchantId)).TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(SettlementModel))).List();

Exception:
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: Unable to perform find[SQL: SQL not available] ---> System.ArgumentException: The value "FeeEngine.Models.SettlementModel" is not of type "LiquidNetORM.Entities.Settlement" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
Parameter name: value
What exactly did I do wrong? Any help is appreciated.
